# Knockout js and sort issues

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I've been searching online and it seems that I cannot make sort work on my observable array. I am definitely wrong somewhere but not sure where, here is the code:

```
var availableProducts = [{"Id":"1","Description":"Product 1","Rate":2956.00},{"Id":"3","Description":"Product 2","Rate":1518.00},{"Id":"2","Description":"Product 3","Rate":750.00}];

function productViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray();
}

var productDetails = new productViewModel();
$(document).ready(function () {

    productDetails.products = (availableProducts);
    ko.applyBindings(productDetails, document.getElementById("product-edit"));

}
```

And HTML looks like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: sortedProducts">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="currency: Rate"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So as it can be seen IDs are in order 1, 3, 2 and I would like to sort them and show them in order, but I cannot seem to sort products. I tried putting following in my ViewModel

```
self.sortedProducts = function () {
    return self.products().sort(function (a,b) {
        return a.Id < b.Id ? -1 : a.Id > b.Id ? 1 : 0;
});
```

This did not work, I tried then adding same code to "$(document).ready(...)" with exception of replacing `self` with `productDetails` but did not work. I do not want to make button to be called to sort my data, I want them sorted before presenting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort function looks OK, although you should check - preferrably with unit tests - whether your supported browsers actually understand the `compareFunction` handed to `Array.prototype.sort`. It's just an issue I ran into a while ago.

1) You are overwriting the `ko.observableArray()` with the native array `availableProducts`- this should give you an error when accessing the property with the getter syntax `self.products()`.

2) The `foreach` binding in your template shouldn't work because you're handing it a plain function rather than an observable array, I'd guess that it actually iterates over the properties of the function object itself (.length, .prototype, .hasOwnProperty etc.).

3) I'd recommend using the [Knockout Projections](https://github.com/stevesanderson/knockout-projections) library that adds efficient observable handling to arrays in case you plan on handling larger arrays. In my experience with over more than say 1000 items in a collection the UI is not as fluid as you'd like it to be without the projections feature.

My take on this would be:

```
var availableProducts = [{"Id":"1","Description":"Product 1","Rate":2956.00},{"Id":"3","Description":"Product 2","Rate":1518.00},{"Id":"2","Description":"Product 3","Rate":750.00}];

function productViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // In case you know the products at this stage you could just
    // specify it as the first argument
    self.products = ko.observableArray(/* [{...}] */);

    // The sorted products are computed from the original ones
    self.sortedProducts = ko.computed(function () {
        // I'd probably use explicit parens for better 
        // readability - I had to look twice to get the comparer :-)
        return self.products().sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.Id < b.Id ? -1 : (a.Id > b.Id ? 1 : 0);
        });

        //// With ko-projections this would become:
        //// (note the missing parens on `products`)
        //return self.products.sort(function (a, b) {
        //    return a.Id < b.Id ? -1 : a.Id > b.Id ? 1 : 0;
        //});
    });  
}

var productDetails = new productViewModel();
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set the observable array value 
    productDetails.products(availableProducts);
    ko.applyBindings(productDetails, document.getElementById("product-edit"));

});
```

Comment: I use `var availableProducts` because this is dynamically loaded so I cannot put data directly into my `ko.observableArray()`, but `ko.computed(...)` indeed worked! I thought for some reason that I have tried ko.computed, but I guess I did not apply it properly. One correction for your current post `.sort(function())` you forgot pass `a,b` variables so it should look like `.sort(function(a,b))` with that correction it works!

Comment: @zuboje: thanks fixed that, that proves that just blindly copying code is not a good idea - only been focusing on the body and missed the parameters :-)